# Vue.js / Webpack deployment for XAAMP testing

Tags: webpack, build, vue.js, xampp

How can I deploy a vue js 2 app to test the build in my XAMPP and ultimately in a shared hosting (1and1 for example). Right now every time I run `npm run build` none of the js, css, and image files link correctly. I have to manually go into the index.html and fix the link and script elements.

In addition, after i get the css to link correctly, then the background images specified in the css file/s have the wrong path generated.

Seems really a pain, to have to manually do this. I have a simple small app to test out, but for larger apps this would get old really fast.

Here's my config/index.js build obj:

```
build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',

    /**
     * Source Maps
     */

    productionSourceMap: true,
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
    devtool: '#source-map',

    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  }
```

ALSO: in my routes I have "/" set to home.vue(for example), but in XAMPP the root page is blank, seems that home.vue does not get stored as the default index page.

```
import Home from '@/components/frontend/Home/home'
{ path: '/', component: Home, name: 'home'}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but haven't been able to get this working right off the bat upon running `npm run build` command yet.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue by making the following changes:

in config/index.js under build object:
`assetsPublicPath: '/dist/'`

and in the router/index.js under new Router object:
`base: '/dist/',`